# Period key stops working after hibernation

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I recently installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my ASUS Vivobook, but I noticed that after hibernation, the period (.) key stops working unless I press the Fn key alongside the period key. After a reboot it works fine. I tried using Xev to test the key and it doesn't produce any event when "broken", but when I use Fn it produces the same event as when working properly. I'm fairly new to Linux and cannot for the life of me figure out the issue.